# How to force an error if file is missing?

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

This snippet of a makefile shall stop the execution if the file `myFile` does not exist:

```
 test:
        if [ -e myFile ] ; then \
            echo "Error Message"; \
        fi;
```

If I replace the echo-statement by `$(error: Error Message); \` the make file is being stopped in both cases. But I need the makefile to be stopped if the file exists.

Comment: Can you explain the exact situation? Which command does generate the `myFile`? I think it's an XY problem.

Comment: Yeah, if an other build process has finished this file is being created. So I need to stop this makefile if this process is finished.

Comment: Is it possible to merge these two project's `Makefile`? I think it would better solution than checking of a file's existence.

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is not a solution for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(error )` is interpreted by make itself, so if it is hit during reading of the file, the error is produced. If you need an error during execution of a recipe, you have to run a command that returns an error exit code. Most straight-forward would be `false` for that, e.g.

```
 test:
        if [ -e myFile ] ; then \
            echo "Error Message"; false; \
        fi;
```

Of course, you could check for the file using `$(shell )`, without a recipe:

```
ifeq ($(shell test -e myFile && echo yes),)
    $(error Error Message)
endif
```

Comment: or you could do `test: myFile`.   As long as myFile doesn't match any pattern rules, make would generate a readable warning that myFile could not be created...